# Can you make a UDF in xlwings running on server?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I'm playing around with [xlwings server](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/pro/server/server.html) and I'm hoping to make use of user-defined functions in this context. I've been testing using it with FastAPI, but am open to others.

I'm able to follow the example well enough to get code to run on my test server (localhost) and make whatever changes to the workbook. That makes sense to me for something where I might have my end-user fill in lots of things and then hit a "calculate" button.

However, what I want to do is use a normal (at least normal-looking to the end-user) user-defined function that actually does the processing on the server. Doing all the processing code in VBA is sometimes possible but even when it is, code management is annoying and updates have to be pushed out to dozens of individual excel files where I'd prefer to just update the backend once.

Here's what I was working with so far:

```py
@app.post("/test")
def test(request: Request):
    headers = request.headers
    val1 = int(headers['val1'])
    val2 = int(headers['val2'])
    return {"result":val1 + val2}
```

Then in VBA I had this:

```vb
Function testfunc(ByRef myVal As Integer, ByRef val2 As Integer) As Integer
    Dim d As Variant
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    d.Add "val1", myVal
    d.Add "val2", val2
    testfunc = runremotepython("http://127.0.0.1:8000/test", exclude:="xlwings.conf", headers:=d)
End Function
```

I then tried to go into the code for runremotepython itself (from xlwings) and set it
so that it returns the 'result' from the server response. This seems bad since I think this xlwings code gets re-written regularly, but just for testing here, it does seem to temporarily work - debugging `testfunc` shows that it does get set to the value I expect

Even this, though, isn't working. It seems that `testfunc()` runs a circular loop on itself? I'm getting a "one or more circular references" warning from excel when I try to run the cell normally.

If there is a way to do this standard, it probably doesn't hacking the xlwings `runremotepython` code...

Comment: You're looking for custom functions: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/pro/server/officejs_custom_functions.html

Comment: @FelixZumstein, thanks a bunch! Been looking more at this functionality and looks super cool. When I first saw 'Office.js' on the xlwings website I thought ".js means javascript, I don't do javascript, I'm not reading anymore". Seems I was a fool for that... tyty

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'll see if I drop the .js then. Microsoft officially calls them just Office add-ins, so that may make sense.